# JSON encode manejo de errores consulta PHP

Tags: php, ajax

recien empiezo en esto y me encontré con una duda que no he conseguido aclarar. Estoy enviando por medio de un formulario dos campos "ciudad" y "calle" a una consulta postgresql. Si existen los datos funciona y me devuelve los valores, pero si alguno no existe me da error. El código javascript mediante el cual envío el formulario es (la salida HTML es mejorable):

```
function objetos(){
    var elemento = document.getElementById("formulario");
    objeto1 = document.getElementById('name');
    objeto2 = document.getElementById('calle');
    var txt='';
    txt = "\""+objeto1.value+"\"";
    txt1= "'"+objeto2.value+"'";
    url_objeto = 'name='+txt+'&calle='+txt1;
    drawObjeto(objeto1.value, objeto2.value);
}
function drawObjeto(nameId, calleId){ 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var url = "namesCalles.php";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = {name: nameId, calle: calleId}
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    var onError = function() {alert('error');}
    xhr.onerror = onError;
    xhr.onload = function(){
        xhr.responseText;
        //console.log(xhr.responseText);
        if(xhr.status === 200){
            var resultados = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            for(var i in resultados.data){
                if(resultados.data[i].name != null){
                    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<p>" + reultados.data[i].name + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("calle").innerHTML = "<p>" + reultados.data[i].calle + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("numero").innerHTML = "<p>" + reultados.data[i].numero + "</p>";
                    document.getElementById("poblacion").innerHTML = "<p>" + reultados.data[i].poblacion + "</p>";
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "<p>Sin datos</p>"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

La consulta PHP:

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$name = $params["name"];
$calle = $params["calle"];

$query="SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE ciudad = 'yes'";

if($name){
    $query .= " AND name_ciudad = :name";
    $params[":name"] = $name;
}
if($calle){
    $query .= " AND calles_ciudad = :calle";
    $params[":calle"] = $calle;
}
$statement = $cnn->prepare( $query );
    
$result= $statement->execute($params);

if( $result ){
    while( $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $data["data"][] = $resultado;
    }
    echo json_encode( $data );
}else{
    echo "error";
}
$statement->closeCursor();
$conexion = null;
```

Me da un Notice

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: data in <b>/var/www/html/objetos.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
null
```

Al no hacer el json_encode($data) me da el error en el javascript.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br />
<b>"... is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at xhr.onload
```

No se cual puede ser la mejor manera de manejar que no tenga datos el json cuando hace el encode en el PHP.

Comment: El error sale porque puede que la consulta no retorne ningún resultado... por lo tanto nunca entra al `while` y `$data` nunca se define... probablemente lo puedas arreglar poniendo un `$data = []` antes del `while`

Comment: Siii, @Pipe ya veo que no se define ya que no devuelve resultados la consulta. Puse el ` $data = [] ` antes del ` while ` y ya no me sale el Notice ni otra cosa. Como hago algo del estilo **No hay datos** , probé en el ` if(xhr.status === 200){...}else{onError();} `definido previamente, pero no me saca mensaje.  Gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias cosas a corregir / mejorar en tu código. A saber:

1. Si en el cliente esperas un JSON, debes responder desde el servidor un JSON en todos los casos, también si no hay datos.
2. Deberías cubrir más casos de error, como el `execute`, el `prepare`, o incluso la conexión (no lo haré aquí por brevedad). No programes nunca de una forma ingenua, debes pensar en todo aquello que pueda salir mal, incorporando una política de manejo de errores. Subrayo que aquí hablamos de *errores lógicos* por llamarlos de algún modo, y que no entran dentro del manejo de errores de la petición Ajax (la cual capturará errores de red, errores fatales en el código como el típico error 500, etc, pero no aquellos casos en que el servidor responderá con un estatus 200, pero no habrá datos).
3. Debes cerrar los recursos antes de devolver la respuesta.
4. En los casos en que haya filas, la forma de llenar el array no es correcta. Si esperas varias filas, debes poner la clave `data` al array por fuera, no dentro del `while`

Aplicando lo dicho, el código quedaría así:

#### En el servidor

```
$data=array();
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$name = $params["name"];
$calle = $params["calle"];

$query="SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE ciudad = 'yes'";

if($name){
    $query .= " AND name_ciudad = :name";
    $params[":name"] = $name;
}
if($calle){
    $query .= " AND calles_ciudad = :calle";
    $params[":calle"] = $calle;
}

if ( $statement = $cnn->prepare( $query ) ) {       
    if( $statement->execute($params) ){
        $rows=array();
        while( $resultado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $rows[] = $resultado;
        }
        if ($rows) {
            $data["data"] = $rows;
        } else {
            $data["error"]="No se encontraron filas";
        }
    }else{
        $data["error"]="Error en el execute";
    }
    $statement->closeCursor();
    $conexion = null;
} else {
    $data["error"]="Error en el prepare";
}
echo json_encode( $data );
exit();
```

#### En el cliente

Verificas si hubo error después de hacer el parse.

```
    if(xhr.status === 200){
        var resultados = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        if (resultados.error) {
            //Hubo error, actuar en consecuencia
        } else {
            //Hay datos, leerlos y/o mostrarlos
            for(var i in resultados.data){
                //Aquí tu lectura de cada fila
            }
        }
```

Comment: Envía esto, por ejemplo, `{"name":"Valencia","calle":"avda de Catalunya"} ` pero al ver la respuesta sale `[ ]`

Comment: @mimartita no entendí tu comentario. ¿Dónde sale eso y qué código usas para mostrar la respuesta?

Comment: @mimartita revisa la respuesta editada. La forma de llenar el array dentro de `while` tampoco era correcta.

Comment: revisada la respuesta editada, ahora si muestra el error en caso de que esté vacío. Gracias me has ayudado muchísimo.