# Enviar datos a PHP usando fetch, llega uno bien y otro mal

Tags: javascript, php, backend, useeffect

Buen dia,

tengo el siguiente codigo en PHP en el servidor que me recibe datos por POST, especificamente dos variables, nombre y edad,
tuve que ponerle

`$_POST=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')`, true);
ya que me estaba insertando en MySql una linea vacia, sin nombre ni ciudad, asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $_POST=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    
    $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'cenpost_prueba', '}_X[Pp]akiY{','cenpost_prueba');//host,user,pass,bd
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo json_encode("No se pudo conectar, mostrando error de MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        //echo "No se pudo conectar, mostrando error de MySql: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }else{
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $ciudad=$_POST['ciudad'];        
mysqli_query($conexion,"INSERT INTO `tabladeprueba`(`nombre`,`ciudad`) VALUES ('$nombre','$ciudad')");
        
mysqli_close($conexion);
echo json_encode("datos insertados");
        
    }
  
?>
```

Envio los datos con el API Fetch de Javascript

```
const enviar = async () => {
                const data = { nombre: "PEDRO", ciudad: "LIMA" };
                try {
                    let response = await fetch('http://xxxxxx.com.co/prueba/prueba.php', {
                        method: "POST",
                        cache: 'no-cache',
                        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                        body: JSON.stringify(data)
                    });
                    if (response.ok) {
                        console.log(response);
                        const rta2 = await response.json();
                        console.log(rta2);
                    }
                    else {
                        throw new Error(response.statusText);
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log("Error al realizar la petición AJAX: " + err.message);
                }
            }
            enviar();
```

la cuestión es que despues de colocar la linea
$_POST=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),

ahora me inserta 2 registros, uno bien y el otro como menciono, con el nombre y ciudad vacia, de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si ahora quiero guardar "MARIA" y "BUENOS AIRES" lo guarda asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En algunos casos, ignoro por qué, los datos no llegan en la super global `$_POST` cuando usas la API Fetch, sino en el flujo de entrada. Antes de `$nombre=$_POST['nombre']; $ciudad=$_POST['ciudad'];` intenta definir la super global de este modo: `$_POST=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/568461/29967) o bien [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/382645/29967) para más detalles. Si sigue sin funcionar, depura la variable con un `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: @A.Cedano funciona perfecto! pero mira que se insertan dos lineas en la base de datos, una igual como pasaba antes que omite el nombre y la ciudad y la otra si funciona bien, alguna idea?

Comment: No entendí tu comentario. Pulsa en [edit] y pon cómo tienes el código ahora.

Comment: Explica cuál es la acción que ocurre en el cliente para que se lance el código fetch (presionar un botón, entrar en una página, cambiar algún elemento en la página etc) y si es posible muestra más contexto de tu Javascript, todo apunta a que esa acción se está lanzando dos veces o que llamas dos veces a `enviar()` o que se quedó código viejo en la caché o algo así.